# Embed an Excel document into a worksheet in another Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel document in which I want to add another Excel document.

I hoped it would be possible in the same manner how we used to embed a Word document in another, using the Insert → Object option. But this doesn't seem to work with Excel.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: This very comprehensive website may help you http://www.youtube.com/user/ExcelIsFun

Comment: @Simon Could you please explain how? All I see is a YouTube channel with thousands of videos on it.

Comment: I was recommending Sandeep to look on there, he may find the answer. If I knew how I would have definitely have posted the answer. Its a very good site (one of the best infact) to learn about excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what issues you are having, but my copies of Excel 2007 and 2010 both allow you to insert another Excel sheet as an object.

1. To do it, you need to click on the ***Insert*** tab in the ribbon, and then click ***Object***.   This will open a dialog window allowing you to set the object to insert.
2. Click on the ***Create from file*** tab to insert your specific file.
3. Click ***Browse*** button and select the file you are looking to insert.
4. There are a few check-boxes for options.  ***Link to file*** will put a reference to the file,
   so any edits made to the embedded workbook will be reflected on the original.
5. ***Display as icon*** will show an Excel icon with the name and location of the original file.
   Leaving this unchecked will embed the sheet itself within a floating, moveable and sizable window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! All this time, I was playing around the "Create New" tab. Didn't even bother to check out the "Create from file" tab as you said. Silly me...