# How can I embed an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets into another Excel workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I just discovered [this Excel feature](https://superuser.com/questions/517833/embed-an-excel-document-into-a-worksheet-in-another-excel-document) that allows a workbook to be embedded in another workbook and even allow updates in the source document to automatically flow through.

By default this embeds only the worksheet that was active when the source workbook was last saved.  I do not see an option to embed multiple worksheets from the same workbook.

Is this possible?

Comment: When I embed the same Excel workbook multiple times, each shows the same worksheet in that workbook.  I want to embed multiple worksheets from the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

This has been bothering me for days aswell untill I found out there is a simpler way of doing this with Excel workbooks.

What you can do is (Im using Excel 2013): 
Select the range you want to copy and copy it
Go to new workbook in which you want to embed the file and right click and select "special paste" and right down there at the bottom under "other pasting options" you can find "linked image (P)"
This is now a linked image of the cells and it has an added benefit that it will always show the same cell range.